# Vue v-for autofocus on new textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, v-for

I'm making a blog and would like the user to be able to create new textareas when they hit enter and for it to autofocus on the newly created textarea. I've tried using the autofocus attribute, but that doesn't work. I've also tried using the nextTick function, but that doesn't work. How do I do this?

```
<div v-for="(value, index) in content">
    <textarea v-model="content[index].value" v-bind:ref="'content-'+index" v-on:keyup.enter="add_content(index)" placeholder="Content" autofocus></textarea>
</div>
```

and `add_content()` is defined as follows:

```
add_content(index) {
    var next = index + 1;
    this.content.splice(next, 0, '');
    //this.$nextTick(() => {this.$refs['content-'+next].contentTextArea.focus()})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path, but `this.$refs['content-'+next]` returns an array, so just access the first one and call `.focus()` on that

```
add_content(index) {
  var next = index + 1;
  this.content.splice(next, 0, {
    value: "Next"
  });
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs["content-" + next][0].focus();
  });
}
```

**Working Example**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      content: [{
        value: "hello"
      }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add_content(index) {
      var next = index + 1;
      this.content.splice(next, 0, {
        value: "Next"
      });
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs["content-" + next][0].focus();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, index) in content">
    <textarea v-model="content[index].value" v-bind:ref="'content-' + index" v-on:keyup.enter="add_content(index);" placeholder="Content" autofocus></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, your value in the array seems to be an object rather than a string, so `splice` in an object rather than an empty string

Comment: Yes! Awesome! I was struggling with that for a while! Thanks!